# Need to create a Lua function dynamically

Tags: function, lua

I am trying to create a Lua function "on the fly", from within another function. The new Lua function, to be called "fx", should operate on a scalar variable -- say, x -- and return f_x(x), where f_x(x) could be something such as "x+1" or "x^2". Importantly, the function name "fx" is given (as it will be used, with this name, from within other functions), but its properties -- specifically, whether it returns "x+1" or "x^2" -- should be modifiable dynamically.

Suppose that "x" is the scalar-valued input variable and that "y" is a string that contains an instruction, such as "x+1" or "x^2", that "fx" is supposed to impose on "x". I've naively tried

```
function make_func (x,y)
   return ( function fx(x) return y end )
end
```

but that doesn't work.

Any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*to be called "fx"*" Functions in Lua don't really have names. Your `make_func` is merely storing the function in a global table entry named "make_func", but the function itself can exist independently of that. So are you trying to make a function that gets stored in a global named "fx", or where exactly do you want to store it?

Comment: @NicolBolas - My apologies for the unintentional vagueness. I would like to use a global named "fx" for the function name.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how "fx" is supposed to enter the picture, but if you have a string that contains potentially executable Lua code (a Lua expression which would compile if done so in a context where "x" exists), then this seems to be a simple case of building a string from bits of Lua code and executing it:

```
function make_func (x, lua_op)
   return dostring("return function(x) return " .. lua_op .. " end")
end
```

This requires `lua_op` to store a string which is a legitimate Lua expression.

If you want to store the function in the global variable "fx", you can do that before returning it:

```
function make_func (x, lua_op)
   fx = dostring("return function(x) return " .. lua_op .. " end")
   return fx
end
```

Comment: Many thanks! A (hopefully easy to answer) follow-up question: Do I need to load a library in order to access `dostring`? The reason I ask is that I don't work with a standalone Lua program, but with LuaTeX, which embeds Lua. LuaTeX doesn't seem to recognize `dostring` natively.

Comment: @Mico: Then you'll have to look up LuaTeX's documentation. If it doesn't provide you with `dostring` or `loadstring` or similar compilation facilities, then you can't do this.

Comment: @Mico Also see if there's a `load` function, which is what `loadstring` is called in 5.3

Comment: I think your answer fits the bill but a better explanation of `x` is that `x` is a formal parameter in the resulting function and is available as such in y, the body code. It will shadow any external use of x.